# Using SAS finance XIRR function on multiple rows with different numbers of variables

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the SAS XIRR function on a dataset. The syntax is:

finance('XIRR',value1, value2, value3...valuen,date1,date2,date3...daten);

My problem is that the data has different numbers of values/dates on each row. There could be up to 122 values/dates per row.

Where there are missing values the XIRR function fails, so I set all missing values to 0. Now the function fails as the 'missing' dates are now Jan1960. Anyone got any ideas?

in the code below cf1-cf122 are the cash flow values and ed1-ed122 are the dates.

````
/* remove blanks */

data irrtable3;
set irrtable2;
   array change _numeric_;
        do over change;
            if change=. then change=0;
        end;
run;

/* create irr */

data irrtable4;
set irrtable3;
IRR=finance('XIRR',OF CF1-CF122,OF ED1-ED122);
run;```
````

Comment: What is the meaning of the dates?  Did you try setting all of the extra dates to the last date instead of zero?

Answer (score 1):

You can use codegen to construct a dynamic `FINANCE(..)` call, with a variable number of arguments, that is resolved by the macro system at DATA step run-time.

Using `RESOLVE` to compute the result in macro environment for many, many rows will likely have a noticeable slowness compared to plain DATA step.

Example:

```
data have;
   v1=−10000; d1=mdy(1, 1, 2008);
   v2=2750; d2=mdy(3, 1, 2008);
   v3=4250; d3=mdy(10, 30, 2008);
   v4=3250; d4=mdy(2, 15, 2009);
   v5=2750; d5=mdy(4, 1, 2009);
   output;

   call missing(v5,d5); output;
   call missing(v4,d4); output;
   call missing(v3,d3); output;
   call missing(v2,d2); output;
run;


options missing=' ';

data want;
  set have;

  args = catx(',', of v1-v5, of d1-d5);

  result = resolve( cats (
    '%sysfunc(FINANCE(XIRR,', args, '))'
  ));

run;

options missing='.';
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell (And I don't work with Finance functions, so I'm not an expert), if you have all of the 'filled' arguments prior to the 'unfilled', you are okay to just set everything to zero that's missing (both on the 'value' and 'date' side).  Using the example Richard provides (which is the one from the SAS documentation):

```
data want2;
  set have;
  
  array v v1-v5;
  array d d1-d5;
  
  do _i_ = 1 to dim(v);
    if missing(v[_i_]) then do;
        v[_i_]=0; d[_i_]=0;
    end;
  end;
  
  args = catx(',', of v1-v5, of d1-d5);

  result =FINANCE('XIRR',of v1-v5, of d1-d5);

run;
```

That works and gets the same result as Richard's, and is probably faster.

This does require the 0s to all be at the end - if they're interspersed, and you can't use CALL SORTN to get them put all on one end - and your data is too big to use with RESOLVE, then I would construct this entirely in the macro language.  You could do a few things, all of which are too long for this answer, but the simplest is probably to create code for every line, and put them behind `if _n_ = 5 then do; &row5code.; end;` for each row.  This would be very long, certainly, but should be faster than the resolve (just a lot less maintainable).  You could also do a CALL EXECUTE for each line, also slow but a possibility, or even DOSUBL.